# Select article(s) only containing N tags

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine

I have two entities, the article entity and the tags entity. There is a ManyToMany relation between theses two entities (an article can have 0->N tags and a tag can be containing in 0->N articles)

I want search articles with some conditions (I must use a querybuilder, magics methods like findBy() aren't enought), one on theses conditions is to select articles containing exactly N specific(s) tag(s)

I tried several times to get the expected result but without success. I think I misunderstand how doctrine works with join tables. My last try:

```
public function search($titles, $tags, $authors)
{

    $query = $this->createQueryBuilder('a') // a = article
        ->orderBy('a.createdAt', 'DESC')
        ->setMaxResults($limit)
        ->setFirstResult($offset);

    if($titles !== null){
        // ...
    }

    // tags is an array of string containing names of searched tags (ex : $tags = ['english', 'french', 'game', 'guide'] )
    if($tags !== null){
        // $query->innerJoin('a.tags', 't');
        // $tagsQuery = "";
        // foreach ($tags as $id => $tag){
        //     if($id > 0) $tagsQuery .= " AND ";
        //     $tagsQuery .= "t.name LIKE :tag_".$id;
        //     $query->setParameter("tag_".$id, '%'.$tag.'%');
        // }
        // $query
        //     ->andWhere($tagsQuery);

        $query->leftjoin ('a.tags','t');
        foreach ($tags as $id => $tag){
        // $query->andWhere("t.name LIKE :tag_".$id);
        // $query->setParameter("tag_".$id, '%'.$tag.'%');
            $query
                ->addSelect('t')
                ->andwhere("t.name LIKE :tag_".$id)
                ->setParameter("tag_".$id, '%'.$tag.'%');
        }
    }

    // ...
```

An example of expected result :

With 3 articles :

```
- id 1 
- tags : 
    - guide
    - game

- id 2 
- tags : 
    - english

- id 3 
- tags : 
    - english
    - guide
```

The method `search(null, ['guide','english'], null)` must return only the article with the id 3

Comment: Do you want to find articles which have exactly n tags (example 3 tags) or do you want to find articles which have all the tags specified in a set (example tagA, tagD and tagZ) or do you want to find articles which have at least one tag of the specified set ?

Comment: hoo good question ! the second choice :) , articles which have all the tags specified in a set (example tagA, tagD and tagZ)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Alexandre tips, I get the solution :)

The code here if someone have the same issue :

```
     foreach ($tags as $id => $tag) {
            $query->innerJoin('a.tags', "t${id}")
                ->andWhere("t${id}.name in (:tag${id})")
                ->setParameter(":tag${id}", $tag);
     }
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to have all articles which have at least one of the specified tags, your code should be something like that:

```php
    public function search($titles, $tags, $authors)
    {

        return $query = $this->createQueryBuilder('a') // a = article
            ->innerJoin('a.tags', 't') //on inner join is enough
            ->where('t.name in (:set)')
            ->setParameter('set', $tags)
            ->orderBy('a.createdAt', 'DESC')
            ->setMaxResults($limit)
            ->setFirstResult($offset)
            ->getQuery()   //retrieve
            ->getResult();
    }
```

This first SQL will do a join. The tips is to use the "in" operator.

If you want articles which have all tags, (exactly all), you should add one inner join for each tag. The tips is to add an alias for each join and to something on the alias which shall be uniq.

```php
    public function search($titles, $tags, $authors)
    {

        $query = $this->createQueryBuilder('a') // a = article;

        foreach ($tags as $index => $tag) {
             $query->innerJoin('a.tags', "t$index")
               ->andWhere("t$index" + ".name in (:tag$index)")
               ->setParameter("tag$index", $tag)
        }

        return $query
            ->orderBy('a.createdAt', 'DESC')
            ->setMaxResults($limit)
            ->setFirstResult($offset)
            ->getQuery()   //retrieve
            ->getResult();
```

Your requests should be something like that. I didn't test them, but this is the template.